# Uncontrolled and dangerous volume level increase breaking my ears and my headsets

Tags: sound, i3-wm

[image]

I've encountered an unusual issue and I need assistance. It started about a year ago. Sometimes, usually once a month, the volume on my device suddenly skyrockets out of control. It increases rapidly, exceeding 1000%, and lasts for about 3-5 seconds before stopping. I remove my headset as fast as I can and turn it off when it happens. This results in extremely loud noise that surpasses the hardware's limits. After one particularly incident, my headset (Logitech G Pro X) stopped working altogether, and I had to purchase a new one (also a G Pro X). I've had frequent ear pain and a persistent buzzing sound during the last month, which makes me concerned that my ears may have been permanently damaged. Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

I'm running Ubuntu with the i3 window manager and Polybar, and I'm wondering if the sound widget might be connected to the issue. I encountered the same problem when I was using Arch Linux. Additionally, I have another laptop with identical configurations and dotfiles, but I don't experience the problem on that device, possibly because I use a different headset with it. Could the headset be the cause of the issue?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Since you have the same problem in Ubuntu and Arch Linux, the problem is not Ubuntu related. Since the problem happens only on one device and not the other, it is 99% certain the problem is hardware related and cannot be reproduced. I am voting to close this question as unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: Software stack details are important as they allow us to recognize what options are available to you (eg. *LTS releases of Ubuntu allow you to change kernel stack easily, and this can sometimes make a huge difference on strange hardware behavior in my experience*) but your question is device of specific details as to what Ubuntu product/release you're using.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu LTS 22.04. The issue may not necessarily be with the headset itself. Even when I turn off the headset directly, the problem persists and the volume level continues to escalate.